# How do I 'Save a Copy' rather than 'Save As' in Acrobat Javascript?

Tags: javascript, acrobat

I have just learned about doing Javascript in Acrobat and I've run into an issue.

I need to 'Save a Copy' of a ton of files to get them out of 'Extend Features in Adobe Reader ' mode. I'm trying to figure out how in JS, so I can batch through all the files.
The only method I could find that seems like it could work is saveAs(). I've tried

```
this.saveAs({cPath:"end/folder/path", bCopy:true});
```

but it just makes an exact duplicate, instead of 'Save a Copy...'. Same thing if I feed pdfa/e/x into the cConvID.

I'm thinking that saveAs() is the wrong method, but I cannot find the right one. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27831573/495455