# How to split a PDF into multiple documents

Tags: pdf, split, adobe, keyword, acrobat

I have a large PDF that has been combined from multiple documents.

**How can I split the PDF back into multiple documents with a keyword delimiter?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As well as Adobe Reader you will need Adobe Acrobat.

Add the following script using the Action Wizard:

[image]

[image]

Paste in the following script and modify for your needs. See //comments for help on customisation.

```
/* Extract Pages into Documents by Keyword */
// Iterates over all pages and find a given string and extracts all 
// pages on which that string is found to a new file.

var pageArray = [];
var pageArrayEnd = [];

var stringToSearchFor = app.response("This Action Script splits the document by a keyword on each X number of pages, please enter the keyword:");

for (var p = 0; p < this.numPages; p++) {
    // iterate over all words
    for (var n = 0; n < this.getPageNumWords(p); n++) {
    // DEBUGGING HELP, UNCOMMENT NEXT LINE, CHANGE TO MATCH MULTIPLE WORDS OR WHAT EVER ORDER, eg if ((this.getPageNthWord(p, n) == stringToSearchFor) && (this.getPageNthWord(p, n + 1) == stringToSearchForTWO)) {..., Also add a prompt for the second search word and iterate one less for (var n = 0; n < this.getPageNumWords(p) - 1; n++) ...
    //app.alert("Word is " + this.getPageNthWord(p, n));
        if (this.getPageNthWord(p, n) == stringToSearchFor) {
            //app.alert("Found word on page " + p + " word number " + n, 3);
            if (pageArray.length > 0) {
                pageArrayEnd.push(p - 1);
            }
            pageArray.push(p);
            break;
        }
    }
}

pageArrayEnd.push(this.numPages - 1);
//app.alert("Number of sub documents " + pageArray.length, 3);
if (pageArray.length > 0) {
    // extract all pages that contain the string into a new document
    for (var n = 0; n < pageArray.length; n++) {
        var d = app.newDoc();    // this will add a blank page - we need to remove that once we are done
            //app.alert("New Doc using pages " + pageArray[n] + " to " + pageArrayEnd[n], 3);
            d.insertPages( {
                            nPage: d.numPages-1,
                            cPath: this.path,
                            nStart: pageArray[n],
                            nEnd: pageArrayEnd[n],
            } );
        // remove the first page
        d.deletePages(0);
        d.saveAs({ cPath: this.path.replace(".pdf","") + n + ".pdf" });
        d.closeDoc(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: You will actually need Adobe _Acrobat_. Adobe Reader would not be able to run this script, because it can not insert nor extract pages. And if you have Acrobat, you will also have Distiller. However, I don't see any reason for Distiller in this context.

Comment: Another thing to keep in mind is that a "word" in PDF may not correspond to a word as we see it in the text. Depending on the software used to create the PDF, it is possible that kerning may break up a word into several "words" in PDF.

Comment: I will post a script that shows each getPageNthWord in a page using the console tomorrow. Thank you for your feedback

Comment: The step to use app.newDoc() may not be necessary; it would be sufficient to extract the first found page, and then insert the pages into that new document. extractPages() does return a Doc object when it executes successfully. This would also prevent possible problems with arbitrary page sizes.

Comment: And one final comment… A way for a "smart search" would be using the Redaction function (which also can use Regular Expressions for finding complex words), and then go through the Annotations, and read out the page numbers from there. A bit of a detour, but even more powerful… Just don't forget to NOT finish the Redaction, but trash all those annotations when done.

Comment: I'd welcome your edits mate,I  spent an hour on getting it working for a colleague this morning. He said he'd been researching free stuff all night so I just chucked the result in here (to help others), I'm not an Acrobat specialist - this was my first action script code ever. Appreciate your tips:)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68403/discussion-between-max-wyss-and-jeremy-thompson).

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at this guide on [how to split PDF into multiple file](http://www.rasteredge.com/how-to/csharp-imaging/pdf-split/):

```
// Used to register all DLL assemblies.
WorkRegistry.Reset();

String inputFilePath = Program.RootPath + "\\" + "1.pdf";
String outputFileName = "Output";
int[] splitIndex = new int[3] { 1, 3, 5 }; // Valid value for each index: 1 to (Page Count - 1).

// Create output PDF file path list
List<String> outputFilePaths = new List<String>();
for (int i = 0; i <= splitIndex.Length; i++)
{
        outputFilePaths.Add(Program.RootPath + "\\" + outputFileName + "_" + i.ToString() + ".pdf");
}

// Split input PDF file to 4 files:
// File 0: page 0.
// File 1: page 1 ~ 2.
// File 2: page 3 ~ 4.
// File 3: page 5 ~ the last page.
PDFDocument.SplitDocument(inputFilePath, splitIndex, outputFilePaths.ToArray());
```