# Adobe Reader/Acrobat JavaScript - Splitting 100+ Page document into separate documents when a certain phrase appears

Tags: javascript, pdf, adobe, acrobat

I have a large PDF document which contains multiple similar documents within it. I have never coded JavaScript, only MS VBA and found that when I convert from PDF to Word the formatting is thrown off.

I would like to look through this PDF document and once a certain word is reached (which is not anywhere except the end of each document) extract the rest of that page and all pages before into a separate document. Then continue performing this procedure until the end of the document.

Comment: You can do it with Acrobat ($$$ version) and AcroJS, but not with Adobe Reader only.

Comment: I have Acrobat and tried this code but it only works with one words..not a phrase like I need.                            http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27831572/how-to-split-a-large-pdf-into-multiple-documents-with-keyword/42099606#42099606

Comment: The script read and compare word by word. If you like to change that, you have to read and store all words of a page an then -or during the process - to search for the phrase, with e.g. s.indexOf(phrase) = something like string Instr (VBS/VBA). The other option would be to use Acrobat IAC (activeX, documented in the Acrobat SDK) and writing the script in VBA (open pdf, read and find text/phrase, split and save the pdfs)