# Performance issue when using old iText for .NET version when splitting a huge PDF

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, itext

My goal here is to split a huge PDF (over 1000 pages).

I tried the example below :

```
public void ExtractPages(string sourcePdfPath, string outputPdfPath, 
    int startPage, int endPage)
{
    PdfReader reader = null;
    Document sourceDocument = null;
    PdfCopy pdfCopyProvider = null;
    PdfImportedPage importedPage = null;
    try
    {
        // Intialize a new PdfReader instance with the contents of the source Pdf file:
        reader = new PdfReader(sourcePdfPath);

        // For simplicity, I am assuming all the pages share the same size
        // and rotation as the first page:
        sourceDocument = new Document(reader.GetPageSizeWithRotation(startPage));

        // Initialize an instance of the PdfCopyClass with the source 
        // document and an output file stream:
        pdfCopyProvider = new PdfCopy(sourceDocument, 
            new System.IO.FileStream(outputPdfPath, System.IO.FileMode.Create));

            sourceDocument.Open();

        // Walk the specified range and add the page copies to the output file:
        for (int i = startPage; i <= endPage; i++)
        {
            importedPage = pdfCopyProvider.GetImportedPage(reader, i);
            pdfCopyProvider.AddPage(importedPage);
        }
        sourceDocument.Close();
        reader.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

It works but it takes more than 10 min.

My question here is there any way to skip the for loop and getting all the pages quickly ??

Comment: What happens if you upgrade to iText 7? The performance of iText with respect to PDF manipulation was improved when we rewrote iText from scratch. The version you're using is being phased out. The latest iText 5 releases are *maintenance* releases, meaning, we only release them if customers require a bug fix, we don't add new functionality, and we don't backport performance enhancements. In other words: we won't answer your question because you are using an outdated iText version. You should switch to [iText 7](https://developers.itextpdf.com/itext7/download-and-install-information/NET).

Comment: By the way: we don't call it iTextSharp anymore; we call it iText for .NET.

Comment: This is how I do it with Adobe Acrobat: https://stackoverflow.com/q/27831572/495455 - what I'm suggesting is a performance benchmark, because that 1000 page pdf is probably HUGE! Upgrade iText either way.